# Crystal Report Formatting and Suppressing

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

1. There are four credit card options for payment; their visibility is being controlled by dynamic values like `VISA MASTER AMEX DISCVR`. Now if `MASTER` is not visible, then move the `AMEX` and `DISCOVER` back result like: `VISA AMEX DISCVR` instead of `VISA       AMEX DISCVR`.
2. A section has checked option to RESET PAGE NUMBER and also it's being suppressed. When it suppresses PAGE NUMBER REST do not work, I want to reset PAGE NUMBER even if its suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

1.

> Right-click on the column you want to move, select Size and Position.
>   To the right of the X Position Adjustment field, click on the X+2
>   conditional formatting icon, and enter a formula like:
>
> IF {?Name} = "BBB"  THEN -2880  ELSE 0
>
> This tool uses a measurement scale of twips in which there are 1440
>   twips to an inch. So if I want to conditionally move the column 2
>   inches to the left if the parameter value equals "BBB", then I will
>   enter a negative 2880 (2-inches times 1440).

from  [here](http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=574209&sid=a7d32761593c8368c0a15993dc1e9918)

2.

> I assume that you have written a formula to reset the page number
>   after each group and you have placed this formula in the group footer
>   and then suppressed the section.
>
> If that is the case, then remove the formula from the group footer and
>   then right click on the group footer, and then click on section
>   expert. In the pop up window, under the 'Common' tab, check the box
>   next to 'Reset Page Number After'.
>
> This will reset the page number to 1 at the end of each group. This
>   will work even if the group footer is suppressed.

from [here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/4176298/page-number-reset-in-footer.html)